# Display error message if no result found

Tags: apex, visualforce

This is the controller snippet. Somehow it doesn't work. I have checked the results and it is `null`, but the error is not showing. I also have `apex:messages` in my VisualForce page.

```
public PageReference doSearch() {
    results =  [SELECT Name, Employee_No__c, Email, ESS_User__c, Phone FROM Contact WHERE Employee_No__c =:searchEmpNo AND SSS_No__c =:searchEmpSSSNo];
    if (results == null){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'No Results Found'));
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: have you add `<apex:pageMessages/>` tag in VF page?  if yes.. you need to rerender this tag when you call doSearch method from any button..

Comment: i have rerender but still, message is not shown @sfdcweb

Comment: Results CANNOT be null (so not sure how you verified it). It will either be an empty list or an error will be thrown (List has no rows for assignment to sObject) if no results are found (if results is not a list)

Comment: try using count() in query, maybe it will work for this scenario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `reRender`, then the issue is here

```
if (results == null){
```

change this to

```
if (results.isEmpty())
```

, because query will return empty list.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
public PageReference doSearch() {
    Integer counter = 0;
    counter =  [Select count() FROM Contact WHERE Employee_No__c =:searchEmpNo AND SSS_No__c =:searchEmpSSSNo ];
    if(counter == 0){
           ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'No Results Found'));


         }
          return null;
   }
```